# Magento what is the different between _tohtml(with underscore) and tohtml

Tags: magento-1.9

i am very new to magento. Can i know what is the different between _tohtml(with underscore) and tohtml? I can't find any related article on using _tohtml. Will appreciate if someone could explain in details on how to use _tohtml.

Answer (score 1):

You can see comments in the method declaration.

tohtml() is a final method which can not be overridden.

But you can override _tohtml() method in the child blocks if needed.

```
   final public function toHtml()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_before', array('block' => $this));
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $this->getModuleName())) {
            return '';
        }
        $html = $this->_loadCache();
        if ($html === false) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /** @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            if ($this->hasData('translate_inline')) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline($this->getData('translate_inline'));
            }

            $this->_beforeToHtml();
            $html = $this->_toHtml();
            $this->_saveCache($html);

            if ($this->hasData('translate_inline')) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
            }
        }
        $html = $this->_afterToHtml($html);

        /**
         * Check framing options
         */
        if ($this->_frameOpenTag) {
            $html = '<'.$this->_frameOpenTag.'>'.$html.'<'.$this->_frameCloseTag.'>';
        }

        /**
         * Use single transport object instance for all blocks
         */
        if (self::$_transportObject === null) {
            self::$_transportObject = new Varien_Object;
        }
        self::$_transportObject->setHtml($html);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_after',
                array('block' => $this, 'transport' => self::$_transportObject));
        $html = self::$_transportObject->getHtml();

        return $html;
    }
```